# Inverted Fill in area chart in Vue Apex Charts

Tags: vue.js, colors, fill, apexcharts, area-chart

Is it possible to display an inverted fill in an area chart?

I am using the Vue-apex-charts library. I'm trying to create a chart that looks like the following where the red region is not stacked up from the baseline, but descends from the top of the chart.

[image: The red color area represents the inverted fill]

```
fill: {
    type: "gradient",
    gradient: {
        shadeIntensity: 0.9,
        opacityFrom: 0.7,
        opacityTo: 0.5,
        stops: [0, 80, 100]
    }
},
```